# Disable Scrapeazon iFrame [Wordpress Plugin: Scrapeazon ]

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, plugins

[image]

I am trying to stylize this frame in the image above on this [website](http://pursedogs.com/designer-dog-bags/) here by taking off the scroll bars, both horizontally and vertically, Also, i'm trying to increase the width, but all efforts seems futile.

```
#scrapeazon-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#scrapeazon-iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: none;
}
```

**nothing over here can be overwritten for some reason?**

HTML shortcode for integration on wordpress;

```
[scrapeazon asin="B074TBRMZK" width="800" height="300" border="false" country="US"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply CSS to HTML that is loaded in an `iframe`, unless you have control over the page loaded in the `iframe` due to **cross-domain resource restrictions**.

But, you can edit CSS at *Scrapeazon* plugin settings.

There are several ways that you can style the *scrapeazon-reviews* `iframe`: by editing your theme’s stylesheet, by adding parameters to each shortcode, or by using the plugin’s built-in responsive style sheet.

To style the `iframe` in your theme’s stylesheet, add classes named `scrapeazon-reviews` and `scrapeazon-api` to your stylesheet, then add the `width`, `height`, `border`, and other parameters you want to style to those classes. For example, copy and paste the following into your stylesheet to make the iframe a 540×540 pixel square with no border:

```
.scrapeazon-reviews {
   width: 540px;
   height: 540px;
   border: none;
}
.scrapeazon-api {
   width: 540px;
}
```

To style the `iframe` by using the shortcode, add `width`, `height`, and `border` as parameters to the shortcode. For example, to accomplish the same formatting as above in shortcode format, use the following shortcode:
`[scrapeazon asin="<your asin>" width="540" height="540" border="false"]`

Append a percent *(%)* symbol to the `width` and `height` values if you are specifying your those values in percentages rather than pixels. You can optionally append `‘px’` instead of the percent symbol to use pixels. If you specify digits only, ScrapeAZon will default to pixels.

To style the `iframe` by using the built-in responsive style sheet (if your site has a responsive design/theme), select the «Use Responsive Style» checkbox on the ScrapeAZon Settings page.